# how do I invoke FS shell in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to run hdfs commands on my pc. but I cant open fs shell. when i try the command
hadoop fs -ls
command it gives error hadoop: command not found. The apche fs shell guide says that we can invoke the shell using
bin/hadoop dfs args (while inside the hadoop home) but what should I use for args part?? 
They are saying some kind of path, but what is the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hum ok I am not sure that I correctly understand your question, but it seems that you want to use hadoop as any other shell command (like `ls`, `mv`, `cp`, etc...). If you want to do it you will have to edit your .bash_profile file like following :

```
~]$ cd 
~]$ vim .bash_profile
```

then add the path to hadoop and the path to hadoop bin

```
export HADOOP_HOME = path/to/hadoop
HADOOP_BIN = $HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

You should have an exported variable called PATH, add your hadoop bin to it

```
PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_BIN
export PATH
```

After saving it you **must** call `source .bash_profile`
Then you should be able to call : `hadoop dfs -ls` from everywhere.
If you do not know where your hadoop is installed use `find`. 
I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. But in my PC there is no .bash_profile file. Instead of that I did above thing to my .profile file. still it is not working.

Comment: What kind of OS do you have, Linux, Mac or Windows ? In fact you have to add the `bin` directory in your PATH variable so when you launch the `hadoop` command your system is able to find it. The Path is an OS variable.

Comment: it's done thanks for the answer. In ubuntu we have to edit .profile file to run hadoop.